# How I2C address mapping done with internal I2C_SLAVE macro?

Tags: i2c

In `ioctl` call below, why must I pass `I2C_SLAVE` as the second argument if I pass the I2C address in third argument?

```
#define I2C_SLAVE 0x0703 /* Use this slave address */
...
int addr = 0x40; /* The I2C address  */
...
if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Fixed up wording and formatting.

Comment: Because `I2C_SLAVE` is the IOCTL code, which tells the device driver what you want done (set the I2C slave address, in this case). The actual address is in `addr`.